# Tensorflow dataloading issue

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm working with an example program that uses the MNIST dataset.

It tries to load the dataset using this line:

```
dataset = tfds.load(name='mnist', split=split)
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
2020-07-30 12:08:17.926262: W tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/google_auth_provider.cc:184] All attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed, returning an empty token. Retrieving token from files failed with "Not found: Could not locate the credentials file.". Retrieving token from GCE failed with "Failed precondition: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 6 meaning 'Couldn't resolve host name', error details: Couldn't resolve host 'metadata'".
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tflynn/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/utils/py_utils.py", line 399, in try_reraise
yield
File "/home/tflynn/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/registered.py", line 244, in builder
return builder_cls(name)(**builder_kwargs)
File "/home/tflynn/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/api_utils.py", line 69, in disallow_positional_args_dec
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tflynn/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_builder.py", line 206, in __init__
self.info.initialize_from_bucket()
File "/home/tflynn/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_info.py", line 423, in initialize_from_bucket
data_files = gcs_utils.gcs_dataset_info_files(self.full_name)
File "/home/tflynn/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/utils/gcs_utils.py", line 71, in gcs_dataset_info_files
return gcs_listdir(posixpath.join(GCS_DATASET_INFO_DIR, dataset_dir))
File "/home/tflynn/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/utils/gcs_utils.py", line 64, in gcs_listdir
if is_gcs_disabled() or not tf.io.gfile.exists(root_dir):
File "/home/tflynn/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", 
line 267, in file_exists_v2
_pywrap_file_io.FileExists(compat.as_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error executing an HTTP 
request: libcurl code 77 meaning 'Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)', 
error details: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: none
when reading metadata of gs://tfds-data/dataset_info/mnist/3.0.1
```

I've searched on google, but couldn't find any other instances of this error with tensorflow. The node is connected to the internet, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue on an Fedora32 system. The directory /etc/ssl/certs/ exists and there is a file ca-bundle.crt. The following command solved the problem:

sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Comment: Thank you! this is the answer that worked for me after searching for so long. My code was working on Ubuntu however, when running on a CentOS based server I was getting an issue. This resolved it!

Answer (score 1):

Probably same as [1]. Run

apt-get update
apt-get install -y ca-certificates

if on linux before executing your code or commands of similar effect on your OS.

[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1022

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I do not have root access on the machine in question. Am trying to get the MNIST data elsewhere and transfer it on to the machine manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to create a symbolic link or install using apt, you can try to upgrade to a more recent version of tfds.  This issue is not present in the nightly build version 3.2.1.

`pip install tfds-nightly`: Released every day, contains the last versions of the datasets.

According to the TensorFlow/datasets [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/2252), one commenter suggests to downgrade to 3.0.0, however; I have not tried this to see if it works.

Comment: This solution works for me, and is useful even when you don't have root access, something the other answers assume.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying CURL couldn't find the file on your computer with root SSL certificates. On my machine this file is stored at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

You can override the path CURL looks for by setting the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable. For example, either add this to the top of your python script/notebook:

```py
import os
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
```

or you could set the environment variable in a shell, e.g.

```sh
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```